# Eclipse: Different compiler warnings for each developer

Tags: eclipse, compiler-warnings

I'm working in a small team of two, with SVN for version control and Java/Eclipse.
The other guy wants to see compiler warnings of a certain kind ("Unqualified access to instance field."), but I don't. So I'm wondering if it's possible in Eclipse to have a different set of compiler warnings for each developer, while still working on the same SVN repository. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add a filter to the Problems view to filter the warnings you don't want to see.  You should also exclude your `.settings` from SVN as Pablo suggested, so that your partner doesn't accidentally pickup this change in his environment via SVN.  To add a filter, click the arrow in Problems view: [image]

See [Eclipse Help](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/cprbview.htm) for more info on the filtering.

Comment: The goal is to have different warnings for each developer. This looks like setting the warnings for everyone, no?

Comment: @pythondude Not unless you're both using the same instance of Eclipse on the same machine.  This is a local Eclipse setting, and excluding .settings should prevent your partner from accidentally acquiring the same setting via SVN.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to avoid pushing to SVN repository the eclipse preference file for the project.

The file is usually called `.settings` located in the project's root directory. You can also check for a directory called `.metadata` also located in the same place.

This way, each developer will have the WARNING-LEVEL settings he/she wants.